# How necessary are gate resistors for MOSFET gate driving?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, layout, gate-driving

I've been studying MOSFET gate driving recently, aiming to understand the importance of layout. To investigate this, I designed a PCB as shown below:
[image: Schematic diagram]
[image: PCB]
[image: 3D render]

In this PCB, I used the FD6288T (https://static.qingshow.net/fortiortech/file/1597746029372.pdf) as the driver IC and the RC80N03 (with typical Qg of 31.6nC, https://atta.szlcsc.com/upload/public/pdf/source/20220811/31B24DD94B09C6C959893E50CE4E120D.pdf) as the MOSFET.

Of course, this design is far from perfect. Firstly, the FD6288T is a half-bridge driver IC, but my circuit doesn't include a half-bridge. Secondly, due to the lack of appropriate loads, I only installed three 1.8k resistors on the board to act as very small loads.

However, based on my personal understanding, ringing belongs to LC oscillation and should be independent of these factors. So, I tested this circuit under these conditions anyway, and the results are as follows:

channel 1,R2=0Ω:

[image]

channel 2,R4=0Ω:

[image]

channel 2,R4=12.8Ω

[image]

channel 3,R6=12.8Ω and R7=3Ω:

[image]

From the oscilloscope, it can be seen that apart from the channel 1 whitch have ridiculous layouts, the other channels do not produce ringing at all. Adding resistors actually slows down the charging and discharging of the gate, which seems to contradict the recommendations in general design guidelines. Is there something wrong with my testing method, or is it generally unnecessary to worry too much about ringing under typical circumstances?

Unfortunately, I currently lack any suitable loads for testing, so I can only conduct tests under these conditions.

The bandwidth of the probes and oscilloscope is 100MHz and 50MHz.All of the waveforms mentioned above were measured at the X1 position, I also attempted X10 attenuation, but no noticeable diffrence on the waveform.

Comment: Some one will probably answer this betterc, so a quick comment. || Ringing does/may occur on gates depending on Murphy, magic and arcane design issues,  and the series resistor helps damp this. || Too fast gate drive can lead to too fast switching (fancy that) and EMI issues. A balance can be useful. || A reverse biased small Schootky electrically and physically close to FET G-S clamps negative gate excursion and damps any gate ringing rapidly.

Comment: Not ringing related, BUT a gate-source zener close to FEt as above & rated just above Vgatedrivemax  voltage clamps Miller capacitance coupled Drain spikes and can improve survival very very very significantly. I ALWAYs use these after seeing what they can do in extreme cases. I had a design which went from fail in minutes to fail never using gate zeners.

Comment: What bandwidth is the scope and probe?  Don't use a probe in the X1 position as it will have a very high input capacitance and low bandwidth that will affect whether you can see any ringing.

Comment: Do put the intended load on your pcb and recheck ringing .It is worse at high currents .

Comment: For interest: What's the spiral 'inductor' for?

Comment: A larger parasitic inductance in the wiring will make ringing more pronounced, which is consistent with the experimental results.

Answer (score 11):

The gate resistor does two things: it dampens the Colpitts or tuned-gate oscillator mode when a very low impedance is connected, and sets switching speed.

Oscillation mode, first:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0jF1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

This is only oscillating at 50MHz, but it can go much higher in practice; the simulation model is fairly crude (I've also modified it slightly, hence the `*`) and isn't intended to represent behavior in this frequency range anyway, but for hand-waving purposes, this will suffice.  (A more representative device model might be made of multiple devices in parallel, representing phase shift at higher frequencies; more on that below.)

In this case, V1 might be a capacitive load, or a long trace (plus L1).  The 3V source represents the voltage midway along the rising or falling edge, and 20V the drain or load voltage at the same moment -- this is a quasi-static representation of what can happen during a switching edge, and the most common misbehavior is emitting a tone burst when the conditions are right (V<sub>DS</sub>, I<sub>D</sub> and gm are high).

Scenarios where this might occur include: using too "stiff" a gate driver; using capacitance to limit slew rate (external C between G-S must be used cautiously); a zener diode to clamp overshoot or (slower) ringing or transients (even the 10s pF of a small zener junction are enough to cause a problem at these frequencies!); etc.  Notice the magnitude of the inductances: these are hardly more than the package inductance alone, and indeed I've observed SuperJunction MOSFETs oscillating around 400MHz during a switching edge, in one of these cases.

---

Modest diversion:

It's a bit ironic that modern power MOSFETs, even in Si, are so high performance that they can oscillate at such frequencies; but not with very much amplitude, or power.  In fact the amplitude is limited because we are well beyond the maximum power cutoff frequency of the device -- even with tuned gate and drain matching networks, you aren't getting full power out of these devices beyond, oh, a couple 10 MHz or so.  Up here, amplitude is limited by internal losses (R<sub>G</sub> and such), and the die is so large relative to the frequency that different MOS cells (or within a given cell, even) aren't operating in unison, but rather there is some phase shift along or between them, and effectively most of them cancel out. Despite this, there is plenty of gain left at high frequencies, conspiring to produce just enough RF to be an emissions or self-interference problem (1 to 10s of V in this condition is typical), but not to be useful as an RF amplifier.

---

Gate resistance is also used to control rise and fall rate, which are in turn used to tune switching rate, and control peak voltage or current overshoot, or emissions.

Note that this is a fairly crude method when applied to modern types, as they are being quite well optimized these days towards minimal C<sub>rss</sub>, i.e. Miller effect has very little, uh, effect, these days -- or, that it has some effect, but not when you would expect it within the switching edge.

For example, TI's NEXFET architecture incorporates a dual-gate structure as well as a single-pillar depletion structure (analogous to SuperJunction, but applied on small scale), which together give remarkably low C<sub>rss</sub>, so much so that, rather than a flat Miller plateau in gate voltage during the switching edge, there is a significant slope to it, and only little relationship between I<sub>G</sub> and d(V<sub>DS</sub>)/dt.

Which is to say, varying external gate resistance, might have only a modest impact on drain dV/dt, or dI/dt, with modern types.

If tighter rate control is desired, I would recommend a small R+C from drain to gate, for dV/dt; even 10pF + 100Ω can have a significant effect, for example, but real values depend on the transistor in question, the drive strength, and what rates are required.  (Note that a resistor is required to avoid oscillation, by the same argument as here!)  Or source inductance to control dI/dt; this can be as simple as package inductance already (e.g. choose TO-220 over D2PAK), or a ferrite bead slipped over the source pin.

---

Regarding your test cases: with such little drain load, you're mostly modeling the gate loop alone, and the results are as expected: more inductance gives more ringing, more resistance gives slower rise.  Note that damping is assured for \$R^2 \gt \frac{L}{C}\$, so your cases span the range around this limit, and you can play with values some more and verify that this is the case.  (L is obviously ESL in the gate loop, and R the ESR; C may be less obvious, but for full-height switching edges, you will find it's \$ C_\text{eq} = \frac{Q_\text{G(tot)}}{V_\text{GS(on)}} \$, not the small-signal (elevated V<sub>DS</sub>) figure in the datasheet.  Notice the C vs. V<sub>DS</sub> plot, which shows primarily C<sub>rss</sub> and C<sub>oss</sub> varying with V<sub>DS</sub>.)

Drain load is important, because for large load resistance, it simply discharges as soon as gate crosses V<sub>GS(th)</sub>, and there's never any gm to oscillate with.  To get some oscillation, try a higher load current: you can simply shunt in a beefier resistor (say a few ohms; drive it in short pulses to avoid power dissipation, and use a large bypass capacitor nearby to keep switching energy away from other things).  You'll also see the effect of drain inductance, leading to voltage overshoot at turn-off, and perhaps oscillation at high frequencies, give or take other effects.

Your driver still may not have low enough resistance, or high enough capacitance, to oscillate.  To force an oscillatory condition, try some capacitance to ground, somewhere along the gate trace.  Maybe scratch off soldermask and try several points.  Even 100pF ought to be enough, assuming you have some drain current being switched, but a few nF or more will make it that much more likely.  You will need an oscilloscope of adequate performance to observe the effect, of course: a 100MHz scope likely isn't enough, and you definitely need 10x or low-Z probes.  Alternately, a spectrum analyzer with near-field probes will do; the tone-burst oscillation will read as a broad peak at frequency, modulated into a forest of peaks depending on repetition rate and duty cycle, and the electric or magnetic field will be most intense near the transistor and connecting leads.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you think resitors contradict the design requirements.

And yes, you do need to worry about ringing, and about the resistors.

The ringing is bad because it means more electromagnetic interference will be emitted by the circuit.

Also too large resistors may turn the FET on too slowly and cause more energy dissipation as heat, both in the FET and the resistor.

So there needs to be a balance what you want, low EMI or fast charging. You need to fill both requirements, and depending on the PCB layout, you can either fill both requiements with some range of resistor values, or if not, then the layout can't work.

But there are also different strength FET driver ICs, like there are different FETs as well. The point with the resistors is that you can just use one driver IC with many FETs and fine-tune the operation to be suitable driving your specific FETs without problems.

Regarding the LC oscillations, that is what causes the ringing. Each wire has inductance and capacitance, even PCB traces and FET legs, and bond wires inside the FET. And fast edges of square wave are step impulses that will trigger oscillation in these parasitic LC structures at their natural frequency of oscillation.

Answer (score 1):

In Smps you have two choices:

1. Use a low gate resistor, i.e. perform fast cutting/switching, but since leakage energy of inductor in power circuit is always presented you have to use a snubber or some active leakage energy harvesting.
2. Use high gate resistor, so leakage energy is dumped on mosfet DS structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the ringing you observing is in part an artifact due to the length of your scope probe and ground loop. Try repeating the measurement with a "stabber probe" (you remove the witches cap and place a little ground loop around the probe). If you're not sure what this is, I'll send a picture.

Answer (score 0):

> How necessary are gate resistors for MOSFET gate driving?

> Adding resistors actually slows down the charging and discharging of the gate, which seems to contradict the recommendations in general design guidelines. Is there something wrong with my testing method, or is it generally unnecessary to worry too much about ringing under typical circumstances?

The need of a gate stopper resistor and its value depend on the application, the driver, and the MOSFET itself along with other conditions such as layout.

Your MOSFET has an "internal" gate resistance of 1.4 Ohms *(typical, but can be max 2.8 Ohms)*. This resistance comes from the manufacturing of the MOSFET (bonding wires, packaging, semiconductor structure, etc).

There's also the output resistance of the driver. Not a number is given in the datasheet, but judging from the dynamic characteristics it's something between 5~10 Ohms I reckon.

So the effective gate resistance is already at least 6 Ohms and can be as high as ~13 Ohms, even without any external gate resistor.

Could this be enough? Depends.

Here are some examples:

- In a half-bridge arrangement, fast risings may cause an unwanted phenomenon called **self turn-on**. This can lead to catastrophic failures. To prevent this you'll need to slow down the switching because the main source of the issue is high dv/dt. The easiest way to slow the switching down is to increase the effective gate resistance.
- In a half-bridge or full-bridge LLC converter, to ensure proper operation (i.e. ZVS - zero-voltage switching) the turn-off of the MOSFETs should be as quick as possible, or in other words the turn-on speed (rising) is not that important but turn-off (falling) is. This allows you to drive the MOSFET directly from the driver (or controller) but to protect the IC you'll need to add a gate resistor to limit the current. But an external turn off transistor will probably be needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXBNd2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sup>At turn on, the effective gate resistance is the sum of RG1, RG2, and D1's dynamic resistance. At turn off, it's only RG2 and Q1's collector-emitter resistance</sup>

- In a linear regulator where the MOSFET is used as a series pass element (e.g. [constant current source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2imn.png)) a gate resistor will probably not be needed.